# How could I convert a list of cluster labels into a vector of indices?

Tags: r, vectorization, cluster-analysis

The toy example I'm currently working with is a list object in R that looks like this:

[[1]]
4 6

[[2]]
1 5

[[3]]
2 8

[[4]]
3 7

And we can interpret this as a clustering where observations 4 and 6 are in cluster 1, observations 1 and 5 are in cluster 2, etc. But I want to get these cluster labels in index form, so I want to convert the list to the vector (2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3). In practice I will have much more than 8 observations. Does anyone know of a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = list(c(4, 6), c(1, 5), c(2, 8), c(3, 7))
i = rep(seq_along(x), lengths(x))
i[order(unlist(x))]
# [1] 2 3 4 1 2 1 4 3
```

Comment: what is `ul`? Could you please provide.

Comment: Sorry, when I was trying out the solution I named `ul = unlist(x)`. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack`

```
with(stack(setNames(x, seq_along(x))), as.integer(ind[order(values)]))
[1] 2 3 4 1 2 1 4 3
```